# How to delete postgresql9.6 database on centos7?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I'm am using postgresql 9.6; while deleting my mrt_210119 database, getting an error like "ERROR: database "mrt_210119" is being accessed by other users DETAIL: There is 1 other session using the database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you cannot drop a database while clients are connected to it.
>   then also, if you want to drop database than you need some sql statement to run which required superuser  and database owner privileges .

first make sure no one connect to database further any more by using below update statement.

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'mydb';`
```

Below select statement terminate all current connection which is connected to database.

```
 SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'mydb';
```

than drop statement-

```
DROP DATABASE mydb;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an active connection to your database, close it. If you don't, try `pkill postgres` and then delete.

Comment: #nasdenkov - where i execute the 'pkill postgres' command ? do you clear it ?

Comment: In the terminal of the machine that is hosting the database service.